# How to Blend Colors of Merged Paths in AI CC2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, blending-objects

Is there a function / tool / proper method for blending the colors of merged paths in Adobe Illustrator (CC '15)? I would specifically like to source a solution which would allow for the automation of gradated tonal transition across an arbitrary amount of distance (pts / pixels) assigned by a variable default value and/or user determined dialog-box number entry.

Please let me know if you know of a way of arriving at this result, or comparable... not using the Gradation tool / function is a top-priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Blend Tool** and **Blend Function** can blend two objects and transition both shape and color of the objects, including using a specified number of steps.

You may want to explore the Blend Tool help documentation: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html

I don't know that this will specifically meet your needs, but it's about the only option to auto-generate middle steps of something.